# Изменение PolygonCollider2D скриптом

Tags: c#, unity3d

Не могу решить проблему. При создании игрового объекта из префаба по высчитанным точкам рисуется треугольник (рисуется ровно и правильно) и эти же точки назначаю вершинами PolygonCollider2D. По моей логике коллайдер должен совпадать с отрисованным треугольником, но его уводит в сторону...

```
pref.GetComponent<PolygonCollider2D>().points = new[]{point1, point2, point3};
pref.GetComponent<PolygonCollider2D>().SetPath(0, new[]{point1, point2, point3});
```

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. Координаты вершин отсчитываются от центра объекта, то есть

```
Vector2 p2 = new Vector2(point2.x - point1.x, point2.y - point1.y);
Vector2 p3 = new Vector2(point3.x - point1.x, point3.y - point1.y);

pref.GetComponent<PolygonCollider2D>().points = new[]{new Vector2(0, 0), p2, p3};
pref.GetComponent<PolygonCollider2D>().SetPath(0, new[]{new Vector2(0, 0), p2, p3});
```

Comment: Не от центра обьекта, а относительно pivot point. В случае свеже созданного полигона pivot находится в центре даного полигона.

Comment: А, вот, за это уточнение спасибо!